# toggle element in react without too many variables

Tags: reactjs

when somebody clicks on a list heading, the particular list should toggle.

I have 100's of list on the same page.

I don't want to have to create 100  variables in state that I can set to true or false to toggle.

Multiple lists could be open at the same time.

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: few days back i created this, check this example on `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/zj6fab5k/ (mainly the logic part), it may help you

Comment: I would create a simple custom controlled component that renders a single list. In the component manage internally the state variable that controls the list visibility, pretty much like the example above. This way you will not bloat the main application state, or parent component state.

Comment: Oh my! Thanks. Works like a charm